# Correct references when using multiple Angular build configurations on same base href

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, angular8

I have an Angular project with an ASP.NET Core back-end. `angular.json` includes 1 production configuration for each supported language as well as a default configuration I use for development, like this:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",

  // Default config used in development
  "options": {
    "outputPath": "wwwroot/dev",
    "deployUrl": "/dev/",
    "index": "src/index.cshtml",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": ["src/assets/"]
  },

  // Other configurations
  "configurations": {

    "en": {
      "outputPath": "wwwroot/dist/en/",
      "deployUrl": "/dist/en/",
      "i18nFile": "src/locale/my_app.en.xtb",
      "i18nFormat": "xtb",
      "i18nLocale": "en",
      // ... bunch of production optimization flags not relevant to this question ... //
      "fileReplacements": [{
        "replace": "src/environment/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environment/environment.en.ts"
      }],
      "assets": ["src/assets"]
    },

    "de": {
      // ... Same as "en" configuration with "en" replaced by "de" ... // 
    },

    "fr": {
      // ... //
    } 

  // More language configurations may be added in the future //
  }
}
```

Which language is going to be used is supposed to depend on the logged in user's profile preference. To achieve this, the ASP.NET Core backend only serves the root endpoint with the following code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
  if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
  {
    // In development, always serve the same index.cshtml irregardless of the user's language
    return View("~/wwwroot/dev/index.cshtml");
  }
  else
  {
    // If in production mode, get the user's language through the authentication server
    var lang = await _userInfo.GetLanguage(CurrentUserId);

    // Try to get the index.cshtml that corresponds to the user's language
    var view = View($"~/wwwroot/dist/{lang}/index.cshtml");
    if (view != null)
      return view;

    // If the application hasn't been built in the user's preferred language, default to English
    return View("~/wwwroot/dist/en/index.cshtml");
  }
}
```

After building with all the different configurations, I get the following tree structure:

```
wwwroot
|--dev
| |--index.cshtml
| |--main.js
| |...
| |--assets
|   |--img1.png
|   |...
|--prod
  |--en
  | |--index.cshtml
  | |...
  |--de
  | |...
  |--fr
  | |...
  |...
```

Because I have set `deployUrl` in the config, Angular sets the correct references to script files (`main.js`, `vendor.js`etc) in `index.cshtml`, like this:

```
<script src="/dev/runtime.js" defer></script><script src="/dev/polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="/dev/polyfills.js" defer></script><script src="/dev/vendor.js" defer></script><script src="/dev/main.js" defer></script>
```

So the Angular code is loaded and it works as it should. However, wherever I reference to an asset, it can't find it. For instance, code like this: `<img class="companylogo" src="/assets/img/company_logo_small.png" alt="My Company" />` will not work, since I have to prefix the src with the deployUrl.

There are a couple of ways I can fix this, none of which is completely satisfying.

1. Put the asset folder directly in wwwroot instead of copying it in the build process. This means that some files in wwwroot will be source controlled while some will be ignored. This also makes testing more difficult. Some of the code actually loads a `csv` file from the assets and parses it; this can't be tested if the csv file isn't part of the project and therefore not available in the testing environment
2. Use `baseHref` in angular.json and use relative paths in references. This causes all urls in the whole app to be prefixed with the baseHref. This is not desirable, because I want multiple users to be able to send links to each other to get to the same page while still using the user's preferred language. Also, an url with `www.example.com/prod/en/...` is very ugly.
3. Set a variable in `environment.ts` that I have to use in every reference. Very tedious.
4. Use ngx-translate so that I don't have to use one build for each language. However, there are some advantages to Angular's native i18n implementation IMO which I'd like to keep.

Are there some other solutions?